# How to use from a powershell a *.pfx certificate used on build pipeline with the download secure file task

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-powershell

I got this problem:
I need to connect to an azure subscrition from a powershell script used on a build pipeline, but for security requirements i can't write user and password on the code, so i have a pfx certificate with the credentials. 
Right now i'm using the task named dowload secure file, to put the certificate on the build. Then i'm trying to access the certificate from the powershell code.

I already test the code on my machine, but when i'm trying to use it on the build pipeline i cannot access the certificate with this

and i got an error like this

Logging in...
D:\a\1\s\Scripts\fileName.ps1 : The Script does not work :The term 'cert.secureFilePath' is not recognized 
as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was 
included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

```
$tenantId  = "xxxxxxxxxxx"
$appId = "zzzzz"
$cert = %DOWNLOADSECUREFILE_SECUREFILEPATH% 
$certThumbprint = $cert.Thumbprint

Write-Host "Logging in...";

Login-AzureRmAccount `
-ServicePrincipal `
-TenantId $tenantId `
-ApplicationId $appId `
-CertificateThumbprint $certThumbprint
```

[Tasks used on the build pipeline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hKO4u.png)

Comment: Output $cert var after assigning it to see what's in there to make sure that environment variable is getting passed properly from the task.

Comment: Make sure you [reference any values passed as a parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=vsts&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#working-with-variables) to the powershell task correctly.

Comment: When i'm trying to Write-Host $env:DOWNLOADSECUREFILE_SECUREFILEPATH the screen doesn't show anything.

Comment: @Vanessa. Have you uploaded the .pfx file to Azure pipeline library as [secure file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/secure-files?view=vsts)?

Comment: @TomSun yes, and also use the download secure file before the powershell task

Answer (score 3):

The full path of the downloaded Secure file is stored to the **$env:DOWNLOADSECUREFILE_SECUREFILEPATH** environment variable. For more information about Download Secure File task please refer to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/download-secure-file?view=vsts).

We could get the certThumbprint with following code

```
$CertificatePath = "$env:DOWNLOADSECUREFILE_SECUREFILEPATH"
$sSecStrPassword = "xxxxx"
$certificateObject = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2
$certificateObject.Import($CertificatePath, $sSecStrPassword, [System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509KeyStorageFlags]::DefaultKeySet)
$thumbprint = $certificateObject.Thumbprint
```

If we don't want to use to user and password in the code directly. We could use the [Azure Pipeline library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/variable-groups?view=vsts&tabs=yaml#create-a-variable-group). And we could reference it in the code.

> If you want to encrypt and securely store the value, choose the "lock" icon at the end of the row. When you're finished adding variables, choose Save

[image]

> You access the value of the variables in a linked variable group in exactly the same way as variables you define within the pipeline itself. For example, to access the value of a variable named customer in a variable group linked to the pipeline, use **$(customer)** in a task parameter or a script. However, secret variables (encrypted variables and key vault variables) cannot be accessed directly in scripts - instead they must be passed as **arguments** to a task

If I add a Variable named **sSecStrPassword**  in the library. Then the code could be changed as following:

```
function GetThumbprintPFX {
 param([string] $CertificatePath, [string]$Password)
 $certificateObject = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2
 $certificateObject.Import($CertificatePath, $Password, [System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509KeyStorageFlags]::DefaultKeySet)
 $thumbprint = $certificateObject.Thumbprint
 return $thumbprint  
}


$thumbprint = GetThumbprintPFX -CertificatePath $env:DOWNLOADSECUREFILE_SECUREFILEPATH -Password '$(sSecStrPassword)'
Write-Host "$thumbprint"
```

Test Result:

[image]

For more information about Variable groups, please refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/variable-groups?view=vsts&tabs=yaml). And Azure Key Vault is another choice for [security requirements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/variable-groups?view=vsts&tabs=yaml#link-secrets-from-an-azure-key-vault-as-variables).

**Update:**

The following is the detail steps to use the pfx file in the Azure Devops pipeline.

1. prepare a .pfx file.
2. Add a download secure file task and upload the pfx file.

[image]

3. create a variable group and add a variable named **sSecStrPassword**

[image]

4. link the variable to the build

[image]

5. Add powershell script task and add the following script in it.

[image]

```
# Write your powershell commands here.

Write-Host $env:DOWNLOADSECUREFILE_SECUREFILEPATH

function GetThumbprintPFX {
 param([string] $CertificatePath, [string]$Password)
 $certificateObject = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2
 $certificateObject.Import($CertificatePath, $Password, [System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509KeyStorageFlags]::DefaultKeySet)
 $thumbprint = $certificateObject.Thumbprint
 return $thumbprint  
}

$thumbprint = GetThumbprintPFX -CertificatePath $env:DOWNLOADSECUREFILE_SECUREFILEPATH -Password '$(sSecStrPassword)'
Write-Host "$thumbprint"
```

6. queue the build and check the result.

[image]

Comment: Hi, I tried your code but i got a message like this: Exception calling "Import" with "3" argument(s): "The path is not of a legal form."

Comment: @vanessa Have you tried to create a sSecStrPassword in the library and link it the variable tab? You could output the $env:DOWNLOADSECUREFILE_SECUREFILEPATH to test it in the pipeline.  You also could test demo code  in the local or azure pipeline with hard code (password). If the password contains special characters, please use '' to escape.  As I metioned use '$(sSecStrPassword)'.   If it works, then could change it with variable  in the azure devops pipeline.

Comment: Hi, i got a new error with this solution Logging in...
D:\a\1\s\Scripts\scriptps.ps1 : The Script does not work :The path is not of a legal form.
At D:\a\_temp\3e212052-1215-40bf-b7fc-ef7c100b8238.ps1:2 char:1
+ . 'D:\a\1\s\Scripts\scriptps.ps1 
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException,scriptps.ps1

Comment: @Vanessa. I have updated the answer with detail steps, you could refer to it.

Comment: Hi, I create a new pipeline just like the example you gave me and i got the following error: "Exception calling "Import" with "3" argument(s): "The specified network password is not correct." I don't know if is related to the autogenerated certificate. I use one that I created before, and exported with the private key, selected pkcs file and the password is encrypted  AES256-SHA256. Should I use another encryption method? Thanks

Comment: It seems that it related to your pfx file.  You could use the following command `makecert -sky exchange -r -n "CN=[CertificateName]" -pe -a sha1 -len 2048 -ss My "[CertificateName].cer ` then install the .cer  on the local machine then export the pfx file with password. For more information please refer to this [document](https://helpdesk.ssls.com/hc/en-us/articles/204395282-How-to-export-SSL-certificate-from-one-IIS-7-server-to-another?mobile_site=true).  I also recommend that you could post another SO thread to get the help  about how to create a pfx file.