# Error MSB3325: Cannot import the following key file

Tags: msbuild, azure-devops, assembly-signing

I have a project hosted in Azure DevOps and there the build is failing with the error message:

> Error MSB3325: Cannot import the following key file: xxxx.pfx. The key
>   file may be password protected. To correct this, try to import the
>   certificate again or manually install the certificate to the Strong
>   Name CSP with the following key container name: VS_KEY_xxxx

This happens after a project has been changed to sign the assembly with a newly generated password protected pfx signing certificate.

I have tried various fixes given in other SO posts and nothing seems to work.

Can anyone with azure-devops expertise help me with this situation.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [SnInstallPfx.exe](https://github.com/honzajscz/SnInstallPfx) and add this in your pipeline as a powershell task

```
- task: PowerShell@2
  env:
    SN_INSTALL_PFX: $(snInstallPfx.secureFilePath)
    MYCERTIFICATE_PFX: $(myCertificatePfx.secureFilePath)
    MYCERTIFICATE_PFX_PASSWORD: $(myCertificatePfxPassword)
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: '&"$($ENV:SN_INSTALL_PFX)" "$($ENV:MYCERTIFICATE_PFX)" "$($ENV:MYCERTIFICATE_PFX_PASSWORD)"'
```

The pfx, exe and password are stored in the Pipeline library as secure files and variables.

For more information, see the following [blog article](https://dhvik.blogspot.com/2020/01/building-strong-named-assemblies-in.html).

Comment: I've spent over a day looking at this, and this was the only solution that worked. It does require an external .exe, but it works.

Answer (score -1):

> Error MSB3325: Cannot import the following key file

You can create a `PowerShell` script and add a PowerShell Script step in your build definition to import the new certificate file before the VSBuild step:

The PowerShell script I used to use:

```
$pfxpath = 'pathtoees.pfx'
$password = 'password'

Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Security
$cert = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2
$cert.Import($pfxpath, $password, [System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509KeyStorageFlags]"PersistKeySet")
$store = new-object system.security.cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Store -argumentlist "MY", CurrentUser
$store.Open([System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.OpenFlags]"ReadWrite")
$store.Add($cert)
$store.Close()
```

And it works fine on my side.

You can check the [similar thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54009357/how-to-use-from-a-powershell-a-pfx-certificate-used-on-build-pipeline-with-the/54015340#54015340) for some more details.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I tried the above script and it does not work. What should be the -argumentlist "MY"?

Comment: What should be the -argumentlist "MY"? I tried it with the key container name (something like VS_KEY_5FC03B158F74XXXX) specified in build error with no luck.