# Azure devops pfx install in remote vm

Tags: azure-devops, ssl-certificate

I am trying to install pfx certificate in my azure vm and saved my pfx file in variable group and saved my pfx password as well.I am using the below yaml script for deployment, but its not working. Certificate is not getting installed in my azure remote vm.

```
trigger:
- master
pool:
vmImage: 'windows-latest'
variables:
- group: certificate-variable
steps:
- task: DownloadSecureFile@1
  name: mySecureFile
  displayName: 'Get the pfx file certificat'
  inputs:
  secureFile: '$(signingCert.secureFilePath)'
  - task: PowerShell@2
  inputs:
  targetType: 'inline'
  script: |
  Write-Host "Start adding the PFX file to the certificate store."
  $pfxpath = '$(mySecureFile.secureFilePath)'
  $password = '$(signingCert.password)'
  Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Security
  $cert =New-Object -TypeName 
  System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2($pfxpath, $password, 
  [System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509KeyStorageFlags]PersistKeySet)
  $store =New-object system.security.cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Store,CurrentUser
  $store.Open([System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.OpenFlags]ReadWrite)
  $store.Add($cert)
  $store.Close()
```

Comment: Thank you. Issue is resolved now.

Comment: Hi @prabhu, Glad to hear that your problem has been solved. if below answer resolved your question, you could [Accept it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) as an Answer , so it could help other community members who get the same issues and we could archive this thread, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this power shell script

```
$pfxpath = '$(mySecureFile.secureFilePath)'
$password = '$(signingCert.password)'

Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Security
$cert = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2
$cert.Import($pfxpath, $password, [System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509KeyStorageFlags]"PersistKeySet")
$store = new-object system.security.cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Store -argumentlist "MY", CurrentUser
$store.Open([System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.OpenFlags]"ReadWrite")
$store.Add($cert)
$store.Close()
```

In addition, we can create a variable group and add a variable named sSecStrPassword to save the password and add the power shell script to use the .pfx certificate used on build pipeline with the download secure file task. You can refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54015340/13903626) for more details.